# How to add a medication's therapeutic class in FHIR?

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

I wonder if there is a way to add a ***therapeutic class*** (see [definition](http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/RoleCode/index.html) with code **DC**) to a medication?

Definition here as well:

> Description: A categorization of medicinal products by their
>   therapeutic properties and/or main therapeutic use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no element for this, so you'll have to add an extension

Comment: The challenge is that the notion of "Therapeutic Class" is a regulatory classification - and the regulations (and classification) of the medication, and in fact the meaning of the classification itself, shift by jurisdiction.  So it's not the sort of thing that can likely ever be represented as a core element.  Each jurisdiction that has such a concept will need to define their own standard extension.